# Single floating point decimal to binary in C

Tags: c, binary, floating-point, decimal

I am trying to write C program that initializes a variable of type `float` to `1000.565300` and extracts relevant fields of the `IEEE 754` representation. I should extract the sign bit (bit 31), the exponent field (bits 30 to 23) and the significant field (bits 22 to 0).  I should use `bit masking` and shift operations to extract these fields. My program should keep the extracted fields in `32-bit unsigned integers` and should print their values in the `hexadecimal` and `binary` formats. And here is my program. I do not know how to `bit masking`

Comment: Smells like homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one easy way to do all this is:

Interpret a float bits as an unsigned: `uint32_t num = *(uint32_t*)&value`

It means: I want to treat the address of value as the address of a 32 bit unsigned and then I want to take the value stored at that address

Sign: `int sign = (~(~0u>>1)&num) ? -1 : 1   //checks if first bit of float is 1 or 0 , if it's 1 then it's a negative number`

exp part: `uint32_t exp = num&0x7F800000`

mantissa : `uint32_t mant = num&0x007FFFFF`

If you don't know masks :

`0x7F800000` : `0 11111111 00000000000000000000000`

`0x007FFFFF` : `0 00000000 11111111111111111111111`

As for printing bits , you can use this function:

```
void printbits(uint32_t num)
{
    for(uint32_t m=~(~0u>>1);m;m>>=1)  // initial m = 100..0 then 0100..0 and so on
      putchar(n&m ? '1' : '0'); 
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: type punning via pointers is invalid (it breaks strict aliasing): use unions or memcpy